Slide title: textbox/placeholder to extend no farther than the text (auto width)
For my standard slide layout, I've added a shadow in the slide title, relative to the slide background, and so I'd like to have those title boxes extend in width all the way till the end of the text but no further.
However I didn't find any setting for the "slide title" placeholder in the slide master that achieves that. That placeholder will still have a fixed width, meaning that text box extends to the full width, leaving the text box almost empty when the title is brief.

I also tried to define the slide title as a simple text box instead of a placeholder, as I know these have some limitations in terms of how one can format them. However, even then I wasn't able to achieve the desired result, and also this somewhat confuses PowerPoint with titles of new vs old slides. Therefore, I think finding the right setting for the built-in slide title placeholder is the way to go.
Using PowerPoint 365.

In the formatting pane, Text Options section, set the text box to Resize shape to fit text and remove the check next to Wrap text in shape.

Well I feel quite silly. I could have sworn that I had already tried that obvious option. I evidently hadn't, as doing that fixed the problem straight away. Thanks!

Glad to hear it. That you got it fixed, that is, not that you feel silly.  :-)
